# Angular 2 code not updating in browser

Tags: angular

I have a tricky problem. I have an express/angular2 app and my code isn't upadating when I reload the page in my browser. Express code is updating fine (I use nodemon), and html pages in angular2 too but my components and services don't update at all, I can delete all the components code and it will still run, what am I doing wrong here ? It used to work but now don't know why, it's not. Any ideas ? Thanks

Comment: What webserver or environment are you using? Something like Apache, Nginx, Vagrant, Docker...?

Comment: Are you running a build before refreshing the page?

Comment: If you mean your code on server then it is caching problem. One way to solve this is to append version into filenames - therfore browser will always take new files. If you mean during developing process I can't say - not enough info.

Comment: It's during the development process, on local machine, i'm just running nodemon, it should take care of all the code, like before, but now don't know what changed, it's just not updating components and services...

Answer (score 1):

If you are not getting new code from your server, it might be caching. To prevent this you can Disable cache from Network tab in Developer tool:

[image]

The other thing you can try is to use a Hard reload or Empty Cache and Hard Reload options from refresh icon dropdown. This dropdown is available when you right click on refresh icon while Developer tool is openned:

[image]

Comment: This is strange behavior. I saw this solution that might help you: https://medium.com/@kevinsimper/dont-use-nodemon-there-are-better-ways-fc016b50b45e

Answer (score 0):

It's all my fault, I forgot to run `npm run tsc:w` on the client side, my bad.

Comment: It's good to hear that you found the cause of your problem.  You could make your answer more helpful for future readers by explaining *how* you diagnosed it, and in particular, which evidence will identify this problem when it's seen elsewhere.